# How to configure generated Sources in e clipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hello When I use mapper annotations my code automaticly generated codes under;

mappers -->target->generated-source->annotations->net->worl->car->agencyportal->service->mappers->UserMapperImp.java

So how can I generated just under the folder which I created mapper folder my own

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your plugins in your pom.xml add this for example, configure your source as you want:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>target/generated-sources/swagger/src/main/java</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example about filling up the configuration it did not work